# ValueErrors etc in Java?

Tags: java, android, error-handling

I'm writing a simple java Android app and as I'm completely new to the language I don't know how to handle errors. In Python for example if somebody enters something that isn't an integer and you have asked for an integer input you can have an 'except ValueError: //do something' line of code. I want to be able to do this in my Android App. Here is the code I need it to work for

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
     EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalprod);
     EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.scrap);
     TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentage);
     Float num1 = Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString());
     Float num2 = Float.parseFloat(e2.getText().toString());
     Float firstsum = num2 / num1;
     Float finalsum = firstsum * 100;
     t1.setText(Float.toString(finalsum)+("%"));
}
```

Comment: Google "java try catch". It's pretty similar to Python. To find out what exception to catch, simply see what happens when you enter a non-float.

Comment: You can also use the attribute inputType in xml for editText and set it to number

Comment: @KavachChandra I've already done that. I just want the app not to crash if you don't enter a number into one of the fields then press the button.

Comment: You aren't able to type anything but numbers if you set the inputType correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Kivy if you really want Python on Android

Just like Python, the Java API documentation will tell you which Exceptions to `catch`.

Here it is `NumberFormatException`

```
 Float num1 = 0, num2 = 0; 
 try { 
     num1 = Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString());
     num2 = Float.parseFloat(e2.getText().toString());
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) { }

 Float firstsum = 0;
 if (num1 != 0) { // divide by zero doesn't need try-catch
     firstsum = num2 / num1;
 }
 Float finalsum = firstsum * 100;
 t1.setText(String.format("%.2f%%", finalsum));
```

Also, you don't need objects. `float` will do

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the section on Exceptions in the Java Tutorials at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/. If you do not understand exceptions, you might struggle coding in Java.

Exceptions are different in Java (compared to other languages). I have written a fair amount of code in Python with almost zero error handling (not a good practice). But the code works. In Java, this is not possible. Because lots of methods return checked exceptions, which you need to handle.